# FTP File Transfer using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to transfer multiple files through FTP from a local directory - `C:\Users\Documents\FTP\*.*` to the Domain.

I've approached like the below.

First I've created a batch script `DISCH.BAT` as below ::

```
open ftp://UID@XXX.XXXXXX.net/outbound/Pre/Release/ 
USERNAME 
PASSWORD 
binary
mput C:\Users\Documents\FTP\*.*
quit
```

I've created another batch file `RUN.BAT` as below :

```
ftp -i -s:C:\Users\Desktop\DISCH.bat
```

When I am running the RUN.BAT ie., the second one, nothing is happening. Can you please advice where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run it? Did you run it from console window (`cmd.exe`) so that you can spot any errors?

Comment: Though if you are trying to run a command-line ftp client from your C# application, instead of native C# code, it's a really bad solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44669001/850848 - And you did respond neither to my comment nor the answer yet!

Comment: I am running it directly... Double clicking `RUN.BAT`

Comment: So no wonder you cannot see what went wrong. Test it in the console. Or add `pause` at the end of the batch file. But anyway, you first have to fix the problem I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `open` is not URL, but only a hostname:

```
open XXX.XXXXXX.net
```

To enter the desired folder, use `cd` command after the credentials:

```
cd /outbound/Pre/Release/
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you for your answer. The FTP Path can be accessed with UID@Domain.NET but not with simple XXXX.net. Can there be a way I can use in this format..??

Comment: You specify the username in the `USERNAME` line in the script. Again, the `open` command takes only hostname, nothing else. All the other information has to be provided using other means. Command-line `ftp.exe` **does not use the concept URL**, which you may know from  Windows explorer or other FTP clients.